# "Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен" - почему?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня две формы (первая форма это основная, а вторая форма как вспомогательная), которые одновременно загружается. Если же пользователь закрыл или случайно закрыл вторую форму (на крестик Х), и снова хочет открыть тот же форму.

```
Clues clues = new Clues(); //это вторая форма
if (clues == null || clues.IsDisposed)
{
    clues.SetDesktopLocation(this.Location.X + this.Width + 1, this.Location.Y);
    clues.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    clues.Show();
}
else
{
    clues.Activate();
}
```

Как можно решить?

Comment: Если форма утилизирована (IsDisposed), то её нужно создать заново с помощью `new`.

Comment: ссылку на вторую форму нужно хранить в свойствах первой формы, а не в стеке как у вас. объекты из стека автоматически удаляются при выходе из локальной функции.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю вы не правильно написали код. Если формы загружается одновременно то скорее свего он должен быть где то

```
 private Clues clues;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clues = new Clues();
        clues.Show();
    }
```

Вы пытаетесь показат форму который уже ликвидирован (`IsDisposed==true`). Код показ формы должно быть так

```
  if (clues == null || clues.IsDisposed)
        {
            clues = new Clues();
            clues.SetDesktopLocation(this.Location.X + this.Width + 1, this.Location.Y);
            clues.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            clues.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            clues.Activate();
        }
```

Comment: Если форма утилизирована (IsDisposed), то её нужно создать заново с помощью `new`.